SNOWFLAKE SQL how to find aggregate sum for each record based on date range but each record has different date range
So I have two tables that look like this:
Table_A



Product
start_date
end_Date




apple
07-23-2022
09-23-2022


apple
04-12-2022
06-24-2022


orange
01-01-2023
12-11-2023



Table_B



Product
date_sold
quantity_sold




apple
08-23-2022
5


apple
05-12-2022
10


apple
05-13-2022
12


orange
03-01-2023
24


orange
04-01-2024
45



I want to find the total sales for each product in Table_A between the start date and end date.
So by the end I have a table like this:



Product
start_date
end_Date
total_sales




apple
07-23-2022
09-23-2022
5


apple
04-12-2022
06-24-2022
22


orange
01-01-2023
12-11-2023
24




Hi - please update your question with the SQL you’ve managed to write so far and explain where, exactly, you’re stuck

You'll join these tables on the Product and whether the date_sold is in the date range in table_a or not, using the BETWEEN operator:
SELECT t1.Product, t1.start_date, t1.end_date, SUM(t2.quantity_sold) as total_sales
FROM table_a t1
   INNER JOIN table_b t2 
      ON t1.Product = t2.Product
      AND t2.date_sold BETWEEN t1.start_date and t1.end_date
GROUP BY t1.Product, t1.start_date, t1.end_date


I would change INNER JOIN to LEFT JOIN other wise product with no sales records won't show up in final result.
